# Add careers link and info to StackAuth

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stackauth

It might be nice to have access to a user's linked careers information via StackAuth if at all possible. One use I had in mind was integration into a sidebar widget.

Answer (score 2):

Careers does not and will not expose the SE API.

Thus it won't be listed in StackAuth.

Comment: Makes sense. Careers has a rather focused purpose and does not really benefit from API access.

Comment: However, it would be interesting for me to access to some statistics. Such as, similar to the public candidate search, better if with an anonymous user list with just their top tags (for instance limited to the first 50 users). This won't really publish any secret information allowing employers to have a free meal, so I don't see why it should be ruled out categorically.