# Is there going to be an API for the Careers site?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is there going to be an API for access to the careers site? I could understand that it would be different to the rest of the Stack Exchange APIs, but I could see that it *could* be useful for use cases such as:

- Integrating with an HR solution
- Allowing developers to apply additional search options for a specialised client.

There does seem to be a precedent, with JobServe setting up [JobG8](http://www.jobg8.com/) to act as a market exchange for jobs via their API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we are not planning on providing a public API for Careers.

Comment: That's a shame, but I guess the situation may change over time.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's another jobs site that does provide an API? So I can keep my canonical employment information there?

Comment: maybe linkedin has such api ?

Comment: I would have used Stack Careers for maintaining canonical information in one place, but apparently [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) is the next best choice.